# Cannot draw two layers at once using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have two map layers that I want to show at once: One is the full data, the other is a filtered version of the data. The map will draw with each of these layers, but not with both at the same time. Any idea what is going on?

I brought in my data using:

```
var contour = $.getJSON("StateParks.json", function(data) {
    var myStyle = {
    "color": "#ff7800",
    "weight":2,
    "opacity": 0.65

    };
```

A. Full data here:

`L.geoJson(data,{
     style: myStyle
     }).addTo(map);
     });`

B. Filter of that data here:
`L.geoJson(data,{
     filter: stateFilter
      }).addTo(map);
      });
      function stateFilter(feature){
         if (feature.properties.State === "Wyoming"){
            return true
         }
 }`

In other words, A will draw, B will draw, but both A and B will not.

My `StateParks.json` has a format similar this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":1,"ParkArea":855,"Name":"Park Name","Picnic":"Yes","State": "Wyoming", "OfficeAddress": "Address"}}
```

Comment: Couldn't replicate this on a quick test with a different data set: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/3ev404hj/ Could you post the whole `$.getJSON` callback for the non-working version with both A and B? It seems like this could be a simple fix, but it's a little hard to tell, when the code is broken up as you have it here.

Comment: You might like to just color Wyoming a different colour, hey? But anyhow, @nathansnider has something that works.

Comment: I'm a beginner--what is a callback? The code posted above is basically my entire code, with the exception of initializing the map at the beginning. My code differs slightly from the jsfiddle example in that I uploaded data from a .json rather than a URL. What can I provide you with to help you help me? I updated info in the question showing how my json looks, if that's at all relevant. Thanks!

Comment: I got it to work by starting over using your jsfiddle as an example. Not sure what the problem was, but I'm happy to have made progress. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. The callback function is just the function that is run when the `getJSON` request completes successfully. In your example, it's the function that starts with `function(data) {`. You can see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for more information.